# UML 2 Profiles Package: How to extend Operation?

Tags: c#, uml, profile, metaclass

I'm in a big trouble with uml profile implementation. The problem is I can't get how can I   extend uml Operation class from Infrastructure::Core::Constructs using Profile?

The Extension association from Profiles package allow metaclass only to be of type Core::Constructs::Class according to uml metamodel.

Is Operation a metaclass? If it is how can I put it as a Core::Consructs::Class? As far as   I see non of the uml metamodel Operation does specialize or implement Core::Constructs::Class.

Please help me.

I'm trying to make my uml profile implementation in C# using third party uml 2.* metamodel implementation in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already found the answer. The thing can be achieved by combining Profiles::Class and Kernel::Operation via generalization.

Answer (score 2):

Some tools might not support operation extension, but if it does here is how.  If you not talking about simple stereotype extension of the model, such as trying to create a data type to use with operations please clarify your question.  The Stereotype just extends the Metaclass operation and then you use the stereotype in the model.  These examples are from IBM RSM and it works well.

**Profile:**

[image: Profile Answer]

**Applying:**

[image: Applying Example]

Comment: Thanx, Ted. But i was talking about metamodel implementation in object-oriented languages.